# Error:Correct the Invalid Field entries in SalesForce

Tags: salesforce

I am new to the `salesforce` and doing `trailhead` from link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/flow_satisfaction/steps/flow_satisfaction_thanks.

I am performing the **Thank Customer** step, which is failing why ?

[image]

I am not too sure what the heck is going on ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same unique name. On the general info tab, enter the following values:

- Name: Thank Customer
- Unique Name: Thank_Customer

Then click on Field Settings tab and enter the following values:

- Unique Name: ThankCustomer
- Textbox: Thank you for your time. On behalf of everyone at Acme
  Wireless, we'd like to thank you for being a customer. Have a great
  day!